# Where are defects stored in the HP ALM Database?

Tags: quality-center, defect-tracking

Starting to look into writing my own reports by extracting ALM data into excel. After looking through the HP documentation on the ALM Database I can't find any table that shows where they are storing data on the defects that are being logged. Does anyone know where this data is being stored?

Update: I have found what they call the "bug" table and its attributes seem to follow what is tracked for defects. Can anyone confirm that the bug table is essentially the defect table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, when I extracted data on reported bugs (or defects in QC/ALM), the BUG table is where I ran my queries on.

Just to check, you can preview your query results when using the Query Builder, or just go right on ahead and generate the report. Then you can compare the content of the BUG table against what you're finding in the Defects module.